# Unable to run android emulator on Mac OS

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-adt

It shows

> #### Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device "test"

and then nothing happens in the console. I have tried deleting all Virtual devices and tried updating SDK and eclipse but all in vain.

I am using ADT eclipse.

P.S its working on actual device

Comment: Is there an emulator-related process running?

Comment: I dont know, if there is any way to check it

Answer (score 0):

## You are not alone.

I am using the ADT Build: v22.6.2-1085508 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with the newest Android SDK tools 22.6.3.

## The emulator never shows up, I have tried various settings.

This is driving me crazy since Monday.

On Tuesday they released the last update to fix issues with Android Wear, at the same time they forget to fix what they have broken.

I am doing Android development since 2008, never had such a messed-up version.

Comment: I am also using 10.6.8

Comment: I just uninstalled and again installed adt bundle, but still the problem is same, yes I am also experiencing it from few days